# identification of Kentak in "The Chrysalids"

Tags: real-location, the-chrysalids

*The Chrysalids* (Wyndham, 1955) is set in post-apocalyptic Labrador. Various localities are referred to (the main town is Waknuk; a nearby town is Kentak; the big city is Rigo). [This site](https://thechrysalidsanswers.wordpress.com/locations-settings/) identifies Rigo with [Rigolet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigolet) and Waknuk with [Wabush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wabush), but I don't see any explanation of Kentak there. I don't see anything obvious in the [list of Newfoundland and Labrador municipalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_municipalities_in_Newfoundland_and_Labrador), or nearby on Google maps:

[image: map of area surrounding Wabush, NL]

(I left out the scale bar, but Wabush to Fermont is about 20 km).

This might be unanswerable, but is there any evidence about whether Wyndham just made up the town or whether it corresponds to some real current-day settlement?

Comment: The other question on this topic has spoiler markup for the locations. Could someone please let me know if they seem necessary?

Comment: No, spoilers don't seem necessary for any of this.